# Datastage Basic - How to Supress "previously undefined" Warning Message in Transform Function

Tags: function, undefined, basic, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I have a datastage routine transform function, that does something a bit more complicated than the following(Takes in Arg1 which can be null):

```
Ans = Len(Arg1)
```

In certain situations I am calling this transform function in a transform stage and for certain rows where I'm passing in a null-able Timestamp column and I believe several null values are getting passed through to my function, when I run my job through datastage director, I see "Finished (See Log)" for my transform stage and a number of warning messages are shown, they basically say this(repeated a bunch of times):

> Program "ABC": Line 2, Variable "Arg1" previously undefined. Empty string used.

I've attempted to catch this condition by using the "[ISNULL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.5?topic=functions-isnull-function)" function to detect it, but unfortunately my efforts have been unsuccessful, I tried the following:

```
If ISNULL(Arg1) THEN
   Ans = 0
END
ELSE IF Arg1 = $Null THEN
   Ans = 0
END
ELSE
   Ans = Len(Arg1)
END
```

Same issue, just a different line number on the warning message.

I don't understand why this is occurring, the "[ISNULL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.5?topic=functions-isnull-function)" function seems to be straight forward, and I believe the error message is referring to the fact that Arg1 is null. I found some posts related to that but I don't have the direct link, is that accurate, does undefined = null in datastage basic, or can I catch this condition some other way?

I've searched extensively, [most](https://www.toolbox.com/tech/oracle/question/datastage-phantom-error-041509/) of what is [written](http://dsxchange.com/viewtopic.php?p=99349) on this application is archaic and ancient and doesn't really provide any relevant information on the warning message itself. Is there a better resource for looking up relevant information on datastage warning messages, I feel as though I'm not understanding a core tenant of datastage. How do I catch this condition inside of the function and suppress the warning message using only datastage basic code(Without changing my input or column type)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RayWurlod was close, it's actually the "[Assigned](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.5?topic=functions-assigned-function)" function that accomplished this, so my final solution looks like:

```
If NOT(ASSIGNED(Arg1)) THEN
   Ans = 0
END
ELSE
   Ans = Len(Arg1)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch this condition with the IsAssigned() function, rather than the IsNull() function.